# вычитание первого взноса при условии его минимальной ставки в %

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Совсем запутался с процентами
в наличии имеем wordpress и плагин cost calculator (внутри него условия по сути на JS )
делаю калькуляторы ипотеки с разными условиями, в первом варианте

```js
var summaz = $1;
var vznos = $2;
var srok = $3;
final_res = (((summaz - vznos) / srok) / 12) + ((((summaz - vznos) / srok) * 0.07) / 12);
return final_res;
```

мы имеем сумму вычитаем из нее платеж в деньгах ну и получаем платеж в месяц при условии 7% годовых

НО, есть вариант сложнее где первый платеж должен быть не менее 15% и тут появляется загвоздка, если в первом варианте я просто там работал с суммой то тут уже нужны реальные проценты, все что смог намудрить вот

```js
var summaz = $1;
var vznos = $2;
var srok = $3;
var vznos15 = ((summaz / 100) * 15);
if (vznos > 15) final_res = ((((summaz - vznos15) - vznos) / srok) / 12) + (((((summaz - vznos15) - vznos) / srok) * 0.07) / 12);
return final_res;
```

но насчитывает что-то очень много, и не понимаю где ошибка, подскажите  пожалуйста, как это допилить правильно, и где и что я делаю не так, мне кажется надо что-то еще сделать со "vznos"  но что...

Answer (score 1):

решение было найдено самостоятельно

```js
var summaz = $1;
var vznos = $2;
var srok = $3;
if (vznos > (summaz * 0.15 )) final_res = (((summaz - (summaz * 0.15) - vznos) / srok) / 12) + ((((summaz - (summaz * 0.15) - vznos) / srok) * 0.07) / 12);
if (vznos < (summaz * 0.15 )) final_res = 0
return final_res;
```

где у нас при вводе данных менее 15% от введенной суммы выводится 0 или любое другое другое значение, а при вводе первого взноса ( в денежном а не процентном эквиваленте) более 15% от суммы уже выводится верное значение в рублях

Comment: vznos == (summaz * 0.15 ), return undefined

Comment: http://1.elenafin19.beget.tech/elementor-1211/   самый нижний все верно работает

Comment: и где же там исходник глянуть можно? 100% он учитывает упомянутый мной случай

Comment: исходник как таковой это плагин с визуальным конструктором полей, а для их подсчета уже вводится кусок условий на JS , вот страница самого калькулятора если интересно  http://cost-calculator.bold-themes.com/new-main-demo/   там и примеры и мануалы есть

Comment: Повторяю суть. Текущее решение завалится при равенстве суммы и 15% взноса. var summaz = 15;
var vznos = 2.25; return undefined

Comment: а, терь понял, да, если они идентичны то результат уходит в отрицательное значение https://i87.fastpic.ru/big/2019/1024/f4/678ff36ef4f1c037c1bbabee3cb39ff4.png 
может подскажите как решить этот момент?

Comment: if (vznos == (summaz * 0.15 )) final_res = [что нужно]